# Dell PowerEdge R710 with 6 450GB SAS Drives Only sees 5?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, dell-poweredge, sas, raid10

I have this weird issue that I've been trying to figure out but been stuck for a week..

Issue Summary below:

- 6 BRAND NEW SAS Cheetah drives 450gb on Poweredge R710.
- Configured Raid 10 with result of 900 GB of storage.
- When I go to BIOs, it only sees Drives 0, 1, 2, 3, and 5.  Does not
  see Drive 4.
- Drives 0, 1, 2, 3, and 5 all have 1 solid green light, which means
  they're online according to Owner's Manual Drive light indicators
- Drive 4 has TWO SOLID GREEN LIGHTS, which doesn't specify anywhere what they mean based on my research.

Questions below:

1. I've replaced the drive in possibility of a bad drive but the result
   is the same upon swapping. Has anyone seen this issue before and
   know what two solid green light indicate?
2. If I get drive 4 to come online some how, will I need to
   reconfigure my raid 10 or will it auto configure with Drive 5, and
   auto-increase my storage space?
3. I currently have installed ESXi 5.5 on it. If I reconfigure the RAID10 to RAID 6, will the drives need to be formatted and will I need to reinstall everything?

I'm using Raid10 on this server as it will be mainly used for Terminal servers.

Comment: Maybe it's configured to be a hot spare?

Comment: I believe the drive 5 is set as a Fault Tolerance looking at BIOs. So I guess that means Drive 4 is just useless at this point?

Answer (score 0):

What does "PD Count" show you in RAID BIOS?

In my case, I created RAID1 with 2 HDDs, so I have 2xPDs and 1xVD:[image: PERC Screenshot]